# Match value by looking on cell below using criteria table (matrix scheme)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I am looking for a solution or an idea how to get correspoding matches if I am having following:

[image: Data]

I would like to have matches where A2 will look at A3 and using criteria table (G:K) to get my corresponding match from schema.

C1->C2 with combination with C2->C3 will give me V1, then C2->C3 with combination C2->C1 will give me V1 and so on...means to look what is in cell below and try to match it from the criteria.

I tried index/match but I think it is not enough..it has to be tweak around.

```
=INDEX($I$2:$M$5;MATCH([@Operation];$I$2:$I$5;0);MATCH([@Operation];$J$1:$M$1;0))
```

Looking forward for some suggests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace [@operation] with direct cell address eg. A2 and then A3
2. Expand the range in the second Match to the left by 1 column.

   `=INDEX($I$2:$M$5;MATCH(A2;$I$2:$I$5;0);MATCH(A3;$I$1:$M$1;0))`